# Ways to avoid using getIdentifier to retrieve text resources?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, android-resources

I noticed that on the [android developer page for getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) it states:

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

I'd like to try to avoid using it but my current implementation depends on it.

In my database I have hundreds of prepopulated entries, for each entry there are 3 associated string resources and an image. In order to access the resources via the entry, I save the resource names as strings in the tuple and then use getIdentifier to load them.

In case my implementation is confusing here are some pictures and example code:

[string resources file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPICP.png)

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5McUG.png)

Example Code:

```
coin = model.getSelectedCoin()!!

    binding.topMedia.setImageResource(
        resources.getIdentifier(coin.imageAddress, "drawable", requireContext().packageName)
    )

    binding.descriptionText.text = resources.getString(
        resources.getIdentifier(coin.description,"string", requireContext().packageName)
    )
```

Is this bad practice? Is there a more efficient implementation that allows me to connect my database entries with their resources?

Answer (score 3):

**You can get text resource from assets folder or from res/raw folder in two ways (*let's assume your file name is **product_json.json***)**

- You can put a file with file name **product_json** in `res/raw` folder and access as below.

  `val inputStream: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.product_json)`
- Or, you can put your file in `assets` folder (if not exist already then you're welcome to create one!) as access as below.

  `val inputStream: InputStream = assets.open(getString("product_json")`

**Note**: assets.open("file_name_with_extension)e.g., `assets.open("product_json.json")`

Using point number 1 above is faster than accessing resources using `val inputStream: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(  resources.getIdentifier(getString(R.string.product_json), "raw", packageName)` as `getIdentifier()` has to go through the iteration over all the string resources. This is very slow and not recommended, thus, IDE static analyzers show the warning of "**Use of this function is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier (e.g. R.foo.bar) than by name (e.g. getIdentifier("bar", "foo", null))**". Using `val inputStream: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.product_json)` is better because system has to just iterate over raw resources.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it is very informative but what about get a drawable like OP show on example code? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could be setting those values outside of a database? Create an object that describes your level, and define the image and description on that object using their resourceIds. Those are basically UI-related values, they shouldn't be in a database at all.